# Faster connection phone-esp32 using browser

Tags: google-chrome, web, arduino, esp32, webapi

I'm looking for a way to quickly communicate with an esp32 via a web app. I quickly explain the idea:
The web app should generate and send 150B arrays to esp32 every no more than 100 ms. It doesn't matter that all packets arrive: in case one gets lost it's not a problem (more than one could be a problem). The important thing is that the newest one arrives as soon as possible. I tried various methods:

1. **BLE** with Web Bluetooth API.
   In case of small packets I don't have big delays and I can send one every 100/120 ms (which is acceptable). The problem arises, however, when the packets get bigger: everything continues to work from a laptop but, with packets of 150 bytes, it takes 10 times the same time from a smartphone (and I need to use a smartphone).
2. **Websockets**.
   To my amazement, websockets appear to be slower than bluetooth and I can't send packets in the time it takes.
3. **UDP**.
   I also tried to use the udp protocol (although they required the use of a native app on a smartphone and not a web app). Probably being local, the times seem to be very similar to those of websockets
4. I also thought of using the **serial** by wiring the phone-esp32 connection but I have some problems with the polyfill of the serial api

My questions are: is there a faster way for phone-esp32 communication (ideally being able to use a browser and not native apps)?
Could bluetooth connection with BLE be faster than upd and websockets?
Do websockets and udp have the same times on a local network?

Comment: The MTU and hence payload for a single packet in BLE are ridiculously small. You probably need 5 or 6 packets to transfer 150B, so slow is normal. I would expect websockets and especially UDP, on the other hand, to be fast. If you don't need reliable delivery, UDP should be a good deal faster than websockets. A 100 ms interval should be easy to reach, but that mostly depends on your implementation on both ends - that's the main suspect here. Note that establishing a TLS connection takes around 2 seconds, so keep your connections open.

Answer (score 0):

You may wanna try my [WebSocket](https://github.com/wachidsusilo/WebSocket) library. I've just tested it, and it can handle 100ms exchanging data back and forth between ESP32 and NodeJS Server. Here is a quick example about how to use it:

#### 1. As Client

```cpp
#include "WSClient.h"
#include "WiFi.h"

WSClient client;
String url = "ws://10.0.0.2:5000";

void onOpen(WSClient&) {
    Serial.println("onOpen: Connected to " + url);
}

void onClose(WSClient&, String reason) {
    Serial.println("onClose: " + reason);
}

void onMessage(WSClient&, String data) {
    Serial.println("onMessage: " + data);
}

void onPing(WSClient&, String data) {
    Serial.println("onPing: " + data);
}

void onPong(WSClient&, String data) {
    Serial.println("onPong: " + data);
}

void onError(WSClient&, String data) {
    Serial.println("onError: " + data);
}

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(115200);

    WiFi.begin("YOUR_WIFI_SSID", "YOUR_WIFI_PASSWORD");
    while (!WiFi.isConnected()) {
        delay(10);
    }
    Serial.println("WiFi Connected");
    delay(1000);

    client.onOpen(onOpen);
    client.onClose(onClose);
    client.onMessage(onMessage);
    client.onPing(onPing);
    client.onPong(onPong);
    client.onError(onError);
    client.begin(url);
}

void loop() {
    if (Serial.available()) {
        String data = Serial.readString();
        if (data.equals("close")) {
            client.close();
        } else if (data.equals("open")) {
            client.begin(url);
        } else {
            client.send(data);
        }
    }
}
```

#### 2. As Server

```cpp
#include "WSServer.h"
#include "WiFi.h"

WSServer server(80);

void onConnection(WSClient& ws) {
    Serial.println("Client Connected: " + ws.remoteIP().toString() + ":" + String(ws.remotePort()));
    ws.onClose([](WSClient& c, String reason) {
        Serial.println("Client Disconnected: " + c.remoteIP().toString() + ":" + String(c.remotePort()) + " - " + reason);
    });
    ws.onMessage([](WSClient& c, String data) {
        c.send(data);
        Serial.println("Client Message: " + c.remoteIP().toString() + ":" + String(c.remotePort()) + " - " + data);
    });
    ws.onPing([](WSClient& c, String data) {
        Serial.println("Client Ping: " + c.remoteIP().toString() + ":" + String(c.remotePort()) + " - " + data);
    });
    ws.onPong([](WSClient& c, String data) {
        Serial.println("Client Pong: " + c.remoteIP().toString() + ":" + String(c.remotePort()) + " - " + data);
    });
    ws.onError([](WSClient& c, String data) {
        Serial.println("Client Error: " + c.remoteIP().toString() + ":" + String(c.remotePort()) + " - " + data);
    });
}

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(115200);

    WiFi.begin("YOUR_WIFI_SSID", "YOUR_WIFI_PASSWORD");
    while (!WiFi.isConnected()) {
        delay(10);
    }
    Serial.println("WiFi Connected");
    delay(1000);

    server.onConnection(onConnection);
    server.begin();
}

void loop() {
    if (Serial.available()) {
        String data = Serial.readString();
        for (auto& c : server.getClients()) {
            c.send(data);
        }
    }
}
```